# Keep form values after page reload - Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter

How can I keep checkboxes selected after the form has been submitted? I found the set_checkbox function in the Codeigniter User Guide, but it doesn't work.

**Form field code from the User Guide**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck', '1'); ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="2" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck', '2'); ?> />
```

I also googled this and found a couple of workarounds, but they were based on previous versions of Codeigniter. And they were based on Form Validation, which isn't necessary for my form, because none of the fields are required.

How can I retain the checkbox field value after the form is submitted?

**UPDATE**: This question is not about form validation and errors. I want to retain the checkbox field value AFTER the page is reloaded. Is jquery a possibility?

Comment: `set_checkbox()` *is* the way to handle this. There must be something else going on. Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: My form input code looks like the User Guide's example; the database is populating with the proper values, but when I refresh the screen, all the values disappear.

Comment: `set_checkbox()` repopulates the checkbox after a form is submitted but fails validation. It does not repopulate a checkbox after manually refreshing the page.

Comment: @Colin, That's what I thought. So my question remains. How can I repopulate the checkbox after the page is refreshed?

Comment: You should consider rewording your question title so that part is clear. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Did you try to see if there are POST/GET values from your form with the checkbox? You could check it and assign the values of checkbox(es).

Comment: @jlafay I'm not sure what you mean; I am storing the values in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CI session to store the form data in the session and retrieve it if there are no POST submitted when page get refreshed. So the logic will be

```
If($this->input->post()){
    /* ...load session class

    ... Fetch form data as u like

    ... Store form data in a session variable */
}else{
   /* ... Load session class 
   ... Check if session variable exist
   ... Load form data from session variable and set the form values */
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am going to give this a try, but conceptually it makes sense to me.